# Как создать INNER JOIN query в JPA Repository

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Я хочу создать создать запросс для нахождения всех совпадающих записей в таблицах, но в случае с таблицами Customers и Payments при попытке создать запрос

```
@Query("SELECT c.customerName, p.amount FROM Customer c INNER JOIN c.payment_customer p")
```

выбрасывается исключение org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: payment_customer of: com.example.model.Customer

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customers")
public class Customer {

private static int customersCount;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer customerNumber;
private String addressLine1;
private String addressLine2;
private String city;
private String contactFirstName;
private String contactLastName;
private String country;
private BigDecimal creditLimit;
private String customerName;
private String phone;
private String postalCode;
private String state;
private Integer salesRepEmployeeNumber;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "salesRepEmployeeNumber", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Employee employee;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order_customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Order> orders;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "payment_customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Payment> payments;

public Customer() {}

public Customer(String addressLine1, String addressLine2, String city, String contactFirstName, String contactLastName,
                String country, BigDecimal creditLimit, String customerName, String phone, String postalCode,
                Integer salesRepEmployeeNumber) {
    super();
    this.customerNumber = ++customersCount;
    this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
    this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
    this.city = city;
    this.contactFirstName = contactFirstName;
    this.contactLastName = contactLastName;
    this.country = country;
    this.creditLimit = creditLimit;
    this.customerName = customerName;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.postalCode = postalCode;
    this.salesRepEmployeeNumber = salesRepEmployeeNumber;
}

public static Integer getCustomersCount() {
    return customersCount;
}

public Integer getCustomerNumber() {
    return customerNumber;
}

public void setCustomerNumber(Integer customerNumber) {
    this.customerNumber = customerNumber;
}

public String getAddressLine1() {
    return addressLine1;
}

public void setAddressLine1(String addressLine1) {
    this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
}

public String getAddressLine2() {
    return addressLine2;
}

public void setAddressLine2(String addressLine2) {
    this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getContactFirstName() {
    return contactFirstName;
}

public void setContactFirstName(String contactFirstName) {
    this.contactFirstName = contactFirstName;
}

public String getContactLastName() {
    return contactLastName;
}

public void setContactLastName(String contactLastName) {
    this.contactLastName = contactLastName;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public BigDecimal getCreditLimit() {
    return creditLimit;
}

public void setCreditLimit(BigDecimal creditLimit) {
    this.creditLimit = creditLimit;
}

public String getCustomerName() {
    return customerName;
}

public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
    this.customerName = customerName;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getPostalCode() {
    return postalCode;
}

public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
    this.postalCode = postalCode;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

public Integer getSalesRepEmployeeNumber() {
    return salesRepEmployeeNumber;
}

public void setSalesRepEmployeeNumber(Integer salesRepEmployeeNumber) {
    this.salesRepEmployeeNumber = salesRepEmployeeNumber;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Customer{" +
            "customerNumber=" + customerNumber +
            ", addressLine1='" + addressLine1 + '\'' +
            ", addressLine2='" + addressLine2 + '\'' +
            ", city='" + city + '\'' +
            ", contactFirstName='" + contactFirstName + '\'' +
            ", contactLastName='" + contactLastName + '\'' +
            ", country='" + country + '\'' +
            ", creditLimit=" + creditLimit +
            ", customerName='" + customerName + '\'' +
            ", phone='" + phone + '\'' +
            ", postalCode='" + postalCode + '\'' +
            ", state='" + state + '\'' +
            ", salesRepEmployeeNumber=" + salesRepEmployeeNumber +
            '}';
}
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name="payments")
public class Payment {

@EmbeddedId
private PaymentPK paymentPK;
private BigDecimal amount;
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date paymentDate;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "customerNumber", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Customer payment_customer;

public Payment() {
}

public Payment(PaymentPK paymentPK, BigDecimal amount, Date paymentDate) {
    super();
    this.paymentPK = paymentPK;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
}

public PaymentPK getPaymentPK() {
    return paymentPK;
}

public void setPaymentPK(PaymentPK paymentPK) {
    this.paymentPK = paymentPK;
}

public BigDecimal getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public Date getPaymentDate() {
    return paymentDate;
}

public void setPaymentDate(Date paymentDate) {
    this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Payment{" +
            "paymentPK=" + paymentPK +
            ", amount=" + amount +
            ", paymentDate=" + paymentDate +
            '}';
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Если используется JPA, то результат можно получить запросом коллекции Customer

```
SELECT c FROM Customer c
```

и до закрытия контекста обратиться через геттер к коллекции

```
private List<Payment> payments;
```

Тогда Hibernate сам сделает нужный запрос и заполнит коллекцию
Есть риск получить N+1 запрос
Тогда можно поменять на запрос

```
SELECT c FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN FETCH с.payments
```